# How to remove the div append values in html?

Tags: javascript, html

i am appending some values to div.But continuosly click on submit multiple times the data is appending .I want to remove some data only before appending new data then how to delete the 
particular span data before appedning data to div.

Comment: Can you show what you have done? Or if you can provide a fiddle of your work

Comment: Confusing post, post the HTML and JS you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear your data using jquery empty function then append your new values to that.

```
$("somediv").empty().append("your html code");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the previous data by the following line and then write code for appending data to that particular div.

```
document.getElementById('IdOfYourDiv').innerHTML="";
```

It would be more better to answer, if you would have post what ever you have tried out.